# Popup of booking form opening behind section below

Tags: html, css, wordpress, divi

I am setting up a booking form on the homepage of https://dwcastricum.nl/en/. When trying to select the number of persons, a popup opens where number of persons can be selected. I can't seem to figure out why the popup is opening under the section below.

I have tried to set the z-index of the row to 9999, tried setting the popup itself to z-index 9999 but it keeps displaying behind it. The date picker next to it doesn't have this issue, but I also don't see any difference in the code. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: remove `overflow: hidden` from `.et_pb_row_1`

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling those to see the difference it makes.

```
.tommy-zeb-wrapper.tommy-zeb-wrapper-mini tommy-person-category-mini .tommy-zeb-person-category-list {
    background: #4778d9;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* display: flex; */
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```